# Next.js is not rendering CSS in Server Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have created next.js application using `npx create-next-app` and have not made any changes to it.

I noticed that `imported .css` styles are being rendered properly in Client Side Render but not on Server Side Render.

According to [Next.js document](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support) imported .css should work just fine.

**_app.js**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "next-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.0.9",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  }
}
```

**CSR:**

[image]

**SSR**

[image]

Comment: Did you use a local http server to host the SSR version?

Answer (score 7):

If you are not in production mode, it's a normal behavior.

The doc stated this: `if you disable JavaScript the CSS will still be loaded in the production build (next start). During development, we require JavaScript to be enabled to provide the best developer experience with Fast Refresh.`

[Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)

Comment: I just did next build and next start to check the production build. Still same issue.

Comment: i have created a new next project and also did next build and next start, styles is loaded. what version are you using?

Comment: I should read the docs better but cheers for this info

Comment: Hey @sravis did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: This works for me. Was wrecking my brain why this was not working on local

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce this broken css you shared by removing this line:

```js
// pages/index.js
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
```

and not:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
```

Comment: of course, you should leave empty styles object there.

Comment: Named import into object doesn't work :(